# How to display parent/child list items

Tags: list, coldfusion, nested

What is the best way to display parent/child list items in Coldfusion? The table contains an id,title,parentID

I would like to display the items in a nested unordered list.

Comment: Please give us sample code. Take the time to give us great examples of exactly what you want, and we will take the time to give you answers.

Comment: Are you asking how to display them (having already fetched them), or how to query them from the DB?  Those are two very different questions.  Also: what DB are you using?  As Evik suggests, your question isn't very well presented.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes the children will come back from the database in what ever order it decides via purposely leaving it out of the ORDER BY statement.  Here is the SQL I used to make and populate the table:

```
CREATE TABLE Testing
(
ID int,
Title varchar(25),
ParentID int
)

INSERT INTO Testing VALUES (1, 'Parent One', null)
INSERT INTO Testing VALUES (2, 'Parent Two', null)
INSERT INTO TESTING VALUES (3, 'First Child of One', 1)
INSERT INTO TESTING VALUES (4, 'Second Child of One', 1)
INSERT INTO TESTING VALUES (5, 'First Child of Two', 2)
INSERT INTO TESTING VALUES (6, 'Parent Three', null)
```

Here is the CFM code.  I did a LEFT OUTER JOIN assuming that some parents might exist that have no children.  I failed to add a check to not display the children "header" if no children exist but a simple CFIF could solve that for the example.  Regardless was just trying to show brief code that I think answers your question and gets you in the right direction:

```
<cfquery name="myQuery" datasource="Testing">
    SELECT  C.ParentID, P.TITLE ParentTitle, C.ID ChildID, C.TITLE ChildTitle
    FROM    Testing P LEFT OUTER JOIN Testing C ON P.ID = C.ParentID
    WHERE   P.ParentID IS NULL
    ORDER   BY P.TITLE
    </cfquery>

<cfoutput query="myQuery" group="ParentTitle">
    Parent = #ParentTitle#<br />
    <cfoutput>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;Child=#ChildTitle#<br />
    </cfoutput>
    <hr />
</cfoutput>
```